# How to execute a function in all files in the git working tree?

Tags: magit, projectile, version-control

How to invoke a function on all files in the git working tree, while opening the ones which have had no opened buffers beforehand?

A potential use case: Check and fix spelling in all project files with flyspell.

Comment: The "all version controlled files" is not clear enough: there might be versioned files, which aren't actually present in file system (maybe they exist in a different branch, or in history), if these should be affected too, the task is a lot harder. Since magit was mentioned, this may be of interest to you: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Comment: I would be very inclined to *not* use Emacs for such cases, unless the processing in question was very hard to do without it.  I think stripping trailing whitespace is not a great example, because it's so trivial to do with `sed` etc that one immediately wonders why you wouldn't do it that way.  I do think the question is valid, though -- it just might benefit from a more appropriate example use-case.

Comment: @phils Thank you, I changed the use case.

Comment: @wvxvw Thanks, you helped a lot. I changed the question to be more precise, and from your suggestion I will work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for some definition of "all files":

```
(defun my-mapc-tracked-files (fn)
  (magit-with-toplevel
    (mapc (lambda (file)
            (with-current-buffer
                (find-file-noselect file)
              (save-excursion
                (goto-char (point-min))
                (funcall fn))))
          (magit-list-files))))
```

You will have to pass a function to this function, like for `mapc`.